Is there any benefit of using a dictionary comprehension if an equivalent dict(zip(a, b)) is possible?
Recently I have been working with dictionaries and I was to told to make dictionaries out of two lists like this:
zipped = {key: value for key, value in zip(drinks, caffeine)}

Later I forgot how to do that and found a different way that seems simpler to me:
zipped = dict(zip(drinks, caffeine))

Is there something worse about using this second example instead of the first?

The second version is really the more elegant way to do the same thing. Go for it.

The difference is really in perfomance and readability. The second example might be faster than the first, but the first is easier to understand, therefore another dev who sees your code will not need to dig in deep to figure out what you wanted to do.

For prototyping, the former is better because you can easily modify it. The second is AFAIK more pythonic.

Not directly related, but I wanted to note that if drinks and caffeine don't have the same number of elements, neither of the two methods will throw any warning or error. Maybe worth doing zip(drinks, caffeine, strict=True)

The first way is more flexible - consider if you need to add a conditional, or transform the key/val with some function call. It also avoids a name lookup of dict.

The first is a bit clearer, the second a tad faster in my experience (I would mostly use the second).

No, dict(whatever) should always be preferred over {k:v for k,v in whatever}, the same as list(whatever) should be preferred over [x for x in whatever]

@Timus the second is definitely cleaner

@JohnCarter the second is just as easy to understand

Dictionary/List comprehensions are great flexible tools. You were taught this way so that the solution was more flexible and aligns with current coding practices. It's a "skill issue" as they say. There's nothing wrong with either. Always read company coding guidelines where possible.

Technically, the OP is using a dictionary comprehension
